# PHP - WordPress - 8 Recent posts, starting with the oldest

Tags: php, wordpress

I dont understand PHP at all, however i have doubts that my question is pretty easy for those who use the language.
My task is quite simple i need a plugin for recent posts to show me the last 8 posts but in reverse order. The oldest first.
This is the plugin
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-responsive-recent-post-slider/
and this is as i suspect the template where this should be added

```
<?php 
function get_wprps_slider( $atts, $content = null ) {
        // setup the query
        extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    "limit" => '',  
    "category" => '',
    "design" => '', 
    "show_date" => '',
    "show_category_name" => '',
    "show_content" => '',
    "content_words_limit" => '',
    "dots"              => '',
    "arrows"            => '',              
    "autoplay"          => '',      
    "autoplay_interval"  => '',             
    "speed"             => '',
    "hide_post"        => '',
    "post_type"       => '',
    "show_author" => '',
    'show_read_more'  => 'true',
), $atts));

// Enqueue required script
wp_enqueue_script( 'wpos-slick-jquery' );

if( $post_type ) { 
    $postType = $post_type; 
} else {
    $postType = 'post';
}
if( $hide_post ) { 
    $hidePost = $hide_post; 
} else {
    $hidePost = array();
}
 if( $show_author ) { 
    $showAuthor = $show_author; 
} else {
    $showAuthor = 'true';
}

if( $limit ) { 
    $posts_per_page = $limit; 
} else {
    $posts_per_page = '8';
}
if( $category ) { 
    $cat = $category; 
} else {
    $cat = '';
}   

if( $design ) { 
    $postdesign = $design; 
} else {
    $postdesign = 'design-1';
}   

if( $show_date ) { 
    $showDate = $show_date; 
} else {
    $showDate = 'true';
}
if( $show_category_name ) { 
    $showCategory = $show_category_name; 
} else {
    $showCategory = 'true';
}
if( $show_content ) { 
    $showContent = $show_content; 
} else {
    $showContent = 'true';
}
 if( $content_words_limit ) { 
    $words_limit = $content_words_limit; 
} else {
    $words_limit = '20';
}

if( $dots ) { 
    $dotsv = $dots; 
} else {
    $dotsv = 'true';
}

if( $arrows ) { 
    $arrowsv = $arrows; 
} else {
    $arrowsv = 'true';
}

if( $autoplay ) { 
    $autoplayv = $autoplay; 
} else {
    $autoplayv = 'true';
}

if( $autoplay_interval ) { 
    $autoplayIntervalv = $autoplay_interval; 
} else {
    $autoplayIntervalv = '3000';
}

if( $speed ) { 
    $speedv = $speed; 
} else {
    $speedv = '300';
}
$showreadmore = ( $show_read_more == 'false' )  ? 'false'   : 'true';

ob_start();

$posts_type     = $postType ;
$orderby        = 'post_date';
$order          = 'DESC';


    $args = array ( 
        'post_type'      => $posts_type, 
        'orderby'        => $orderby, 
        'order'          => $order,
        'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page, 
        'cat'       => $cat

        ); 

        if(!empty($hidePost)){
            $hidePosId = explode(',',$hidePost);
            $args['post__not_in'] = $hidePosId;
        }

    $query = new WP_Query($args);
  $post_count = $query->post_count;

         if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
         ?>
    <div class="recent-post-slider <?php echo $postdesign; ?>">
            <?php
         while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();


         switch ($postdesign) {
             case "design-1":
                include('designs/design-1.php');
                break;
             case "design-2":
                include('designs/design-2.php');
                break;
             case "design-3":
                include('designs/design-3.php');
                break;
             case "design-4":
                include('designs/design-4.php');
                break;          
             default:                    
                    include('designs/design-1.php');
                }


                endwhile; ?>
      </div><!-- #post-## -->       
      <?php
        endif; ?>

        <?php
         wp_reset_query(); 
         ?>
         <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.recent-post-slider.<?php echo $postdesign; ?>').slick({
        dots: <?php echo $dotsv; ?>,
        infinite: true,
        arrows: <?php echo $arrowsv; ?>,
        speed: <?php echo $speedv; ?>,
        autoplay: <?php echo $autoplayv; ?>,                        
        autoplaySpeed: <?php echo $autoplayIntervalv; ?>,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        responsive: [
{
  breakpoint: 768,
  settings: {
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    infinite: true,
    dots: true
  }
},
{
  breakpoint: 640,
  settings: {
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1
  }
},
{
  breakpoint: 480,
  settings: {
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1
  }
}
]
    });
});
</script>
         <?php              
    return ob_get_clean();                       
}
add_shortcode('recent_post_slider','get_wprps_slider');


function wprps_limit_words($string, $word_limit)
 {
$words = explode(' ', $string, ($word_limit + 1));
if(count($words) > $word_limit)
array_pop($words);
return implode(' ', $words);
  }


 }
```

I deleted small part at the end, as it seems it was managing shortcodes.

Thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 1):

You want to change

```
$order = 'DESC';
```

to

```
$order = 'ASC';
```

The 8 posts is already the limit.

Comment: I cannot. If i do this it will take the 8 first ever posts.
I need the last posts but reverse order.